Collection expression 'List<int> = [1,2]' make red line in Jetbarin Rider, but no error
Code:
List<int> list = [1,2];


This code can be builded without any error.
But in Rider, it makes red line.

When i get on curser in red line, it states like these.



How do i remove this?

This is a C# 12 language feature. Rider is an IDE and as such is not always up to date with the latest language features.
Their current Rider (and Resharper) Release Candidates already contain support for this, you will have to wait until it is actually released, or download the Early Acceess version.

You can always use the older C# language versions:
List<int> list = new() { 1, 2 };

Or even older:
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };


Despite I alredy know this method can resolve my problem, I can't change like this because of my superior.
My superior always wrote List code like '[1,2,3]'. And I have no authority to change this code...

Then you will have no other choice than to use the same IDE your boss uses. That is not a technical problem, that is a "my boss tells me what to do" problem. They probably use Visual Studio. Or you can install the EAP version of Rider.

You are right. What I'm looking for is not a code issue, but a way to set it up. My boss and I haven't been able to find any differences in settings, and we're both using Rider, not Visual Studio. I couldn't solve the problem, so I asked here with Rider Tag.

Then your boss is already using the EAP or Release Candidate Version I talked about.

If you are using the "toolbox" to install Rider, click the three dots on the right of the "rider" menu and select "Other Versions". In the list there should be the Release Candidate" on top. You can install that. Please note that it would probably be better to develop with safe released versions, but that is up to you and your boss.
